# Unable to resolve NPM publish error with bob build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, node-modules

I am trying to publish a package to NPM but getting few errors for bob build , I installed bob module globally too, does anyone know how to resolve this error for publishing the package?

Trying using `npm publish` or `yarn publish` but getting error as per attachment

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @user366584 have you found a solution to this? I am encountering the same strange behavior...